# how to create hidden files in linux-vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

what command will create a **hidden** file for this purpose called **.htpasswd** within our **/etc/apache2** configuration directory.

I need to run the following:

sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd sam

but what step I should do before to create the .htpasswd

Answer (score 0):

There is no any special magic to create a hidden file in Linux.

You just prefix a filename or folder name with ".", then it will be hidden.

In your case `sudo touch /etc/apache2/.htpasswd`.

check it `ll -a /etc/apache2/`

you will see the hidden file.

Hope this help.